# I Try to start a while loop with a start button and stop it with a stop button but i cant find a way that work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Try to start a while loop with a start button and stop it with a stop button but i cant find a way that work.

I use tkinker in Python 3.7

I tried this but it will not work

Did someone have some fixes for me or helpful tips.

```
import time
import sys
from tkinter import *

x = 1

fenster = Tk()
fenster.title("test")
fenster.geometry("600x300")


def start():
    start1()
    time.sleep(5)
    startini()

def start1():
    x = 0

def startini():
    if x < 1:
        while x < 1:
            print(x)
            timer.sleep(5)
    elif x > 0:
        print("stop")

btstart = Button(fenster, text="Start", command=start)
btstart.pack()

def stop():
    stop1()
    time.sleep(5)
    startini()

def stop1():
    x = 1
btstop = Button(fenster, text="Stop", command=stop)
btstop.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: "Will not work" is a bit generic. You should be more specific. Please, make the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get the functionality you want with `after`. Your problem is that the while loop blocks your program from continuing :

```
import time
import sys
from tkinter import *

x = 1

fenster = Tk()
fenster.title("test")
fenster.geometry("600x300")

def start():
    global x
    x= 0
    myloop()


def myloop():
    if x < 1:
        print(x)
        fenster.after(2000,myloop)
    elif x > 0:
        print("stop")

def stop():
    global x
    x=1

btstart = Button(fenster, text="Start", command=start)
btstart.pack()
btstop = Button(fenster, text="Stop", command=stop)
btstop.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Reference to x

Please, have a look at how [python namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) work.

In your functions, you clearly intend to refer to the `x` you created outside the functions. In this case you need to declare it `global.` For example:

```
def start1():
    global x
    x = 0
```

and:

```
def startini():
    global x  
    if x < 1:
        while x < 1:
            print(x)
            time.sleep(5)
    elif x > 0:
        print("stop")
```

and so on in all your functions where you use `x`. Now the loop will work, but you will discover that after you press the *start* button, you cannot stop it by pressing the button *stop*, because the GUI will be frozen. The loop will go on forever.

#### How to not freeze the GUI

To be able to stop the loop, you need `threading`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371815/how-can-i-stop-my-tkinter-gui-from-freezing-when-i-click-my-button) to know why (that question uses to python2.7, but the reason is the same).
In your case should be enough to add `import threading` at the beginning of your script, and edit the `start()` function in this way:

```
def start():
    start1()
    time.sleep(5)
    thr = threading.Thread(target=startini)
    thr.start()
```

Comment: When i press start
<pre><code>
0
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\cygwin64\home\hello.py", line 54, in stop
    startini()
  File "C:\cygwin64\home\hello.py", line 41, in startini
    timer.sleep(5)
NameError: name 'timer' is not defined
</code></pre>

Comment: In your code you have `timer.sleep(5)`. Should be `time.sleep(5)`