# Connecting to telegram using telethon with tkinter without freezing GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, telethon

I'm planning to make a simple app where I can send message to other people in telegram with a tkinter GUI without freezing. Here is my current code:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
import tkinter as tk

class TelegramApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        width = master.winfo_screenwidth() - round(master.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.5)
        height = master.winfo_screenheight() - round(master.winfo_screenheight() * 0.1)
        x = master.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - width // 2
        y = master.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - height // 2
        master.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, x, y))

        self.btn = tk.Button(master, text="ah", command=self.connect)
        self.btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def connect(self):
        client.connect()
        if not client.is_user_authorized():
            client.send_code_request(phone)
            client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
        else:
            main()

root = tk.Tk()
app = TelegramApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Right now when I click the self.btn, it freezes the GUI but it successfully connects. I'm planning to add an input box that I can enter any username, an input box where I can enter messages, both accompanied by a button that will send the message to that username. I'm also planning a list box where it will get all my groups and list it there so i can select a group etc... **Basically I just want the GUI to be able to do all that work without freezing.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-can-i-stop-my-tkinter-gui-from-freezing-when-i-click-my-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371815)

Comment: nope it gives an error "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'TelegramBaseClient.connect' was never awaited"